# ODBC Driver Manager Error in OLE DB Provider

Tags: asp-classic

i have tried this

1. Start Registry Editor by typing regedit in Run window
2. Select the following key in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC
3. On the Security menu, click Permissions.
4. Grant Full Permission for the account which is being used for making connection .
5. Quit Registry Editor.

Also tried this: [ERROR : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283460/error-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-defau)

and also tried this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306345

but not get solution......

Comment: show some code, how you are connecting to the db

Answer (score 0):

I think while you were making database connection, you wrote wrong db name in your codes.