# How to get data from Excel based on values of first column which is serial number but not the serial number of excel its a user defined serial number

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

### S No. | Name  | Phone Number |  Address

### 1     |  Ram  | 234          | Delhi

### 2     | Shyam | 235          | Bangalore

### 3     | Geeta | 236          | Jharkand

### 4     | Raju  | 237          |  UP

### 5     |Chandu | 238          |  Mumbai

How can I get data from above mentioned table based on the serial number?

I want to get address of 4th  row so what logic should be used?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use JDBC ODBC for Excel.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" + 
                    "Dbq=C:\\__tmp\\Book1.xlsx;");

            PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [S No] = ?");

            // pass the serial number you want to retrieve.
            s.setString(1, "1");
            s.execute();
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
            if (rs!=null) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("Name") +"," + rs.getInt("Phone Number"));
                }
            }
            s.close();

            conn.close();
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot but i find  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified error while exceuting this code.

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283460/error-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-defau

Comment: Hi can it be done using Apache POI, where phone number, last name are fetched based on the serial number??

Comment: @SamujjalDasChoudhury, no, its not possible