# Unable to connect to MySQL database - no default driver specified

Tags: mysql, vbscript

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database from within a VBS script, but I can't get passes a specific error -

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7 (from where the script is running), and the MySQL DB is running on 32-bit Linux.  I've tried both the 32- and 64-bit drivers on Windows 7, downloaded from the [Download Connector/ODBC page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) on the MySQL website, but the error persists.

I have found a couple of pages about this issue (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283460/error-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-defau)), but I've been unable to resolve my issue.  How can I make the DB connection I require?

```
Dim Connection : Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim RS : Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim dbConStr : dbConStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3.6 Driver};Server=https://mysqlserver.mydomain.com;Data Source=dsn_hb; Database=MyDatabase; User=MyUser; Password=MyPassword;"

Connection.Open dbConStr
RS.open "SELECT * FROM apklibrary.djg_local_archive_scans", Connection, 3
RS.MoveFirst

While Not RS.EOF
    Call MsgBox (RS.Fields(0), vbOkOnly, "POW!")
    RS.MoveNext
Wend

Connection.close

Set Connection = Nothing
Set RS = Nothing

Call MsgBox ("No more records to show you.", vbOkOnly, "Job done")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it look like `Server=https://mysqlserver.mydomain.com; Data Source=dsn_hbSource` (the semicolon ; is what I mean) in your dbConStr? Simple typo?

Comment: Well spotted, I've corrected that in the example, sadly it wasn't the issue in real life though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specified driver name is invalid. Valid MyODBC 5.3 driver names:

```
{MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}
{MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}
```

Another problem is `Server`. You should specify the server's address without `https://`.

Also, since you have user name and password `Data Source=dsn_hb;` looks redundant, remove it. If not please give us more detail.

So, give a try this:

```
dbConStr = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=mysqlserver.mydomain.com;Database=MyDatabase;User=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;"
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, that has cleared the issue as described in my question.  Unfortunately I am still encountering a problem though, with the message `[MySQL][ODCBC(w) Driver]Unknown MySQL server host (2)` displayed.  The server address is 100% correct, and is accessible from my current location.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out that I was using the incorrect server address for this type of connection.  All sorted, thanks for you help.