# Connect to SQL Server using DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I am trying to connect to MS SQL server using Perl Script. Here is the Code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

#my $dbfile = "sample.db";

my $dsn      = "dbi:ODBC:SQLServer:dpnsql";
my $user     = "xxx";
my $password = "******";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, 
{
   PrintError       => 0,
   RaiseError       => 1,
   AutoCommit       => 1,
   FetchHashKeyName => 'NAME_lc',
}
);


$dbh->disconnect;
```

But I am getting the error as below
[image]

Please help me in this issue. Any new code is also appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Please don't post text as images. It is very difficult to read, and impossible to copy and paste. You should also remember our many blind subscribers.

Comment: @Borodin: I'm not entirely blind (85%), but I couldn't agree with you more :)

Answer (score 2):

The error says that Data source name not found.

That means your `dsn` is incorrect.

If you're working with an x64 server, keep in mind that there are different ODBC settings for x86 and x64 applications. [See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034297/257635]

Try the below syntax with correct DSN.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=<IP>;UID=$user;PWD=$password",
    {
       PrintError       => 0,
       RaiseError       => 1,
       AutoCommit       => 1,
       FetchHashKeyName => 'NAME_lc',
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you suggest me the right way to get the correct DSN ?